# Java equivalent to C#'s StreamReader.ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#, java, inputstream, streamreader

What would a be a Java equivalent to the following

```
// C#
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    String responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    ....
}
```

Currently I have

```
//Java
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

InputStream responseBody = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: So you want to have the contents in "one-go" - is that what you want? We used Apache IOUtils.toString(InputStream) method for this issue, see this JavaDoc https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: Yes, getting all the content in "one-go" was this intention. This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's http client, which I think you're using, comes with a [EntityUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) class for getting the string from a method.

This method using the character encoding specified in the response.  There are overloads available if different encodings are required.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little long, but if you didn't want to use 3rd party libraries you could do this:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("file");
byte[] b = new byte[stream.available()];
stream.read(b);
String file = new String(b);
```

Comment: It's best to specify an encoding when going from bytes to characters.

Comment: This looks nice. However, may I ask what assures that this actually reads to the end of the InputStream, especially if it's an input stream from a socket connection?

Comment: `stream.available()` might or might not contain a number that is exactly the amount that is left to read. This is not a reliable technique.